# How to print out a key together with an average number from an ArrayList in HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have been able to write the codes but I can't print out the Key and the   corresponding average number.

Here is my code:

```
Map<String,List<Double>> stdMap = new HashMap<>();

//Create arraylist of integers to store student's marks

//Create and initialise at creation

ArrayList<Double> Mark1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(78.0,68.0,82.0));
ArrayList<Double> Mark2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(80.0,73.0));
ArrayList<Double> Mark3 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(72.0,81.0,75.0));
ArrayList<Double> Mark4 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(83.0,76.0,65.0,93.0));
ArrayList<Double> Mark5 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(85.0,78.0,77.0));

//Add content to HashMap
stdMap.put("Nii", Mark1);
stdMap.put("Felicity", Mark2);
stdMap.put("Evelyn", Mark3);
stdMap.put("Samuelis", Mark4);
stdMap.put("Bertina", Mark5);  //(1a)Print out Each student's content from hashmap
     System.out.println("\tStudent Results: \n");
     for(Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Double>>stdMapEntry: stdMap.entrySet()){
        System.out.println("\t\t Student Name:" + stdMapEntry.getKey());
        System.out.println("\t\t Student Marks:" + stdMapEntry.getValue()+"\n");
    }
//(1b) Finding the Average Mark of Each Student
     System.out.println("\tAverage Mark: \n");


for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Double>> stdMapEntry: stdMap.entrySet()) {
        double averageNumber;
        double sum = 0;

    String key = stdMapEntry.getKey();           
    for(int i=0; i<stdMapEntry.getValue().size(); i++){
        sum += stdMapEntry.getValue().get(i);

    }   
    averageNumber = sum / stdMapEntry.getValue().size();
    System.out.println("\nThis is the averaged map: ");
    System.out.println(stdMap.put(key, averageNumber)); // won't work
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calculating the average value just fine, but you are trying to insert the average value back into the Hashmap. Since the hashmap has a **value** of type ArrayList but you are inserting a double into it, this will give a compile time error.

HashMap is unordered, so it doesn't necessarily give the entrySet in the same order the data has been inserted in (Like an ArrayList). So the order of entrySet you are obtaining could be different. If the order of the result doesn't matter, you could just print the key and average value without inserting it back into Hashmap.

You can modify your code like this:

```html
for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Double>> stdMapEntry: stdMap.entrySet()) {
            double averageNumber;
            double sum = 0;

            System.out.println("key: " + stdMapEntry.getKey());

            String key = stdMapEntry.getKey();
            for(int i=0; i<stdMapEntry.getValue().size(); i++){
                sum += stdMapEntry.getValue().get(i);

            }
            averageNumber = sum / stdMapEntry.getValue().size();
            System.out.println("average value:" + averageNumber);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much your code was very helpful including the explanation